# AlamoFireImage cache filtered and original image

Tags: swift, caching, filter, alamofireimage

When applying a filter, the filtered image gets cached:

```
let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeWithRoundedCornersFilter(
   size: kSize,
   radius: kRadius
)

myImageView.af_setImage(
   withURL: imageUrl,
   placeholderImage: placeholderImage,
   filter: filter
)
```

But afterwards, when I do a request for the NOT filtered image (the original image), it is not cached:

```
myImageView.af_setImage(
   withURL: imageUrl,
   placeholderImage: placeholderImage
)
```

In the first call the original image is downloaded, but only the filtered image is cached. I would like that the filtered image AND the original image get cached at once in the first call. Is there a possibility to do this elegantly? Thanks!